# Pylons and zombie processes

Tags: python, pylons, multiprocessing, zombie-process

I'm trying to write an application that will allow the user to start long-running calculation processes (a few hours, for example). To do so, I use Python `Popen()` function. As long as the main Pylons process works fine, everything is good, but when I restart the Pylons process, it doesn't respond to any requests if there are any zombie processes left from the previous paster launch.

What could be the origin or a workaround for this problem?

Thanks in advance, Ivan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid zombie processes, the child must do a double fork to detach itself from the controlling process. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process

So all you need to do is make your child process fork again - while being careful to keep the relevant file handles open so that you can still communicate.

Comment: Are there alternate ways that will work both on Linux and Windows?

Answer (score -1):

You need some kind of message passing. This maybe done by installing a signal handler. Python has the `signal` module for this and `Popen` has a `send_signal` method.

Maybe http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/subprocess/#signaling-between-processes helps you too.

Comment: I guess you didn't understand my problem. I use 0mq to pass data between processes, but web-server process freezes if there are zombie processes left. The goal is to understand the origin of the problem and to learn how to make Pylons process work normally.

Comment: The best option would be to pick them up and continue communicating with them. The main problem in avoiding zombie processes is that the web server process can be terminated without any warning, so there is no easy way to know if it is still running.